# How do I import animations into blender through FBX

Tags: .fbx

I have imported a .fbx file in hopes that it would have animations packaged into it

I was wrong, and turns out it has like 51 separate .fbx files for each animation, I wonder if it is possible to import them, into the current armature without having to use 51 separate armatures for it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure. If you import an fbx file, the actions (animations) of it automatically will be added to the project and you can find them in the Action Editor (inside the Dope Sheet). So just import a model, then immediately delete it, and repeat the proccess. But never forget to add fake user (little shield icon near the action name) to the actions, because otherwise they won't be saved. 
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/dope_sheet/action.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html